# I can't set security to None on my wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, security

I have a TV which is broken in either software or something else,  I can't enter keyboard input from the remote controller, yet I can STILL control it. Either way, past that, I need to connect to wifi and I can't input any characters into the TV. So I decided to remove the password of my wifi for a couple hours when I need to use the internet on the TV only.. (Like watching a movie)

I have a `HUAWEI HG658 V2 Home` with these info

```
Hardware version:   VER.B
Software version:   HG658V2C163B021
```

When I go to internet settings, I set the security to `None` and click save it says "it is not safe". I understand that it is not safe (please don't comment how it is not safe, I already understand all the risks). Yet nothing happens and it doesn't work. How can I remove password from my Wi-Fi ?

Here is a picture: It shows not safe. If it doesn't even allow to change that setting, why does it have it in the list ? I want to remove the password from my wifi.

[image]

Comment: Was the router sold in a country that legally forbids 'open' networks?

Comment: If the router belongs to your ISP, ask for a firmware update. The screenshot seems to imply that the security was set to None, but it may be misleading. Try to find more security settings in the router related to this mode.

Comment: yes it is misleading, if i reload the page it goes back to WPA security. No there are public wi-fis where I live

Comment: Use a USB keyboard in the TV's USB port. Don't bother with wifi - arrow keys and space do most of the menu movement, and you should be able to type the WPA key